# Subsets of finite sets of linearly independent vectors are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Larson Edwards Falvo - Elementary Linear Algebra

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

I don't understand the part in red. Please explain what exactly is the contradiction here.

(WOLOG?) S can be $v_1, v_2, ..., v_k, v_{k+1}$ and so $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} c_iv_i = 0 \to c_i = 0$

So what if $\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_iv_i = 0, c_j \ne 0$?

WOLOG, suppose it is $c_1$. Then $v_1$ can be written as a linear combination of $v_2, ..., v_k$. Then I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I disagree with the WLOG assumption (and it's unnecessary anyway). Moving forward, the use of quantifiers should clear things up here. Following your attempt, I'd write "(...) and so **for all scalars** $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} (c_iv_i) = 0 \to c_i = 0$". Do you see the contradiction now?

Comment: @GitGud I guess. Choose $c_{k+1}=0$? I don't quite see what the book is saying though

Comment: No. You don't have to choose anything. The text behind the red boxes tells you that there exist scalars $c_1, \ldots ,c_k$ (where at least one isn't $0$) such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} (c_iv_i) =0$. What is the negation of this statement?

Comment: @GitGud There does not exist a nonzero vector $c = (c_1, ..., c_k)$ s.t. $c \cdot v = 0$ i.e. $c=0$ [?](https://youtu.be/8AWN_JvrWmE?t=74)

Comment: Correct. Now can you rewrite that as a universal statement?

Comment: @GitGud $\forall c, c \cdot v = 0$? Oh wait I think I got it. Choose $c_{k+1} = - 1$?

Comment: @GitGud Wait, it's not $c_{k+1} = 0$? See egreg's answer

Comment: Let's work with formulas. Behind the red box it says that $$\exists c_1, \ldots, c_k\exists j\in \{1,\ldots ,k\}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} (c_iv_i) =0\land c_j\neq 0\right).$$
Since there's no $c_{k+1}$ inside the parentheses this is equivalent to $$\exists c_1, \ldots, c_k,c_{k+1}\exists j\in \{1,\ldots ,k\}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} (c_iv_i) =0\land c_j\neq 0\right).$$
The negation of the last formula is $$\forall c_1, \ldots, c_k,c_{k+1}\forall j\in \{1,\ldots ,k\}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} (c_iv_i) =0\implies c_j= 0\right).$$

Comment: But this formula is the first formula you wrote below the rex box. So behind the red box it says one thing, and when one negates that thing one gets what you wrote. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @GitGud ah thanks. In your opinion, the book clearly means that? I don't think that's obvious :(

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $T=\{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2\} \subset \{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2, \mathbf{v}_3\} = S.$

If $T$ is a linearly dependent set of vectors, then there are scalars $c_1,c_2$ such that $c_1\mathbf{v}_1 + c_2\mathbf{v}_2 = \mathbf 0$ and $c_1,c_2$ are not both $0$.

Therefore there are scalars $c_1,c_2,c_3$ (where $c_3=0$) such that $c_1\mathbf{v}_1 + c_2\mathbf{v}_2 + c_3\mathbf{c}_3 = \mathbf 0$ (the two scalars $c_1,c_2$ are still the same scalars they were above).

Therefore $S$ would not be linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks Michael Hardy, but what exactly is the book saying? Why is it impossible that $v_i \in S$ and $S$ is linearly independent? Is it possibly left to the reader to fill in the gaps with something like what you said?

Answer (score 1):

Let $T=\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ and $S=\{v_1,\dots,v_k,v_{k+1},\dots,v_n\}$; suppose $T$ is linearly dependent. If $c_1,\dots,c_k$ are scalars, not all zero, such that $c_1v_1+\dots+c_kv_k=0$, set $c_{k+1}=\dots=c_n=0$; then $c_1,\dots,c_n$ are scalars, not all zero, such that
$$
c_1v_1+\dots+c_kv_k+c_{k+1}v_{k+1}+\dots+c_nv_n=0
$$
and therefore $S$ is linearly dependent.

(This is a proof by contrapositive, rather than by contradiction.)

Alternative way: suppose $S$ is linearly independent and suppose $c_1v_1+\dots+c_kv_k=0$; set $c_{k+1}=\dots=c_n=0$ so that
$$
c_1v_1+\dots+c_kv_k+c_{k+1}v_{k+1}+\dots+c_nv_n=0
$$
By linear independence of $S$ you get $c_1=\dots=c_k=0$.

---

The “without loss of generality” can be justified by the fact that $T$ can be obtained from $S$ by successively removing one element; thus you just need to prove the statement when $T$ is obtained from $S$ by removing one element. However, I don't think this makes the proof clearer: the above one is just applying the definitions. I find the book's suggestions at least misleading.

Comment: The contradiction is that by the linear dependence of $T$ we have $c := (c_1, ..., c_k)^T \ne 0$ but by the linear independence of $S$ we can choose $c_{k+1} = ... = c_n = 0$ to have $c=0$?

Comment: @BCLC Not really; we have $c=(c_1,\dots,c_k)^T\ne0$; on the other hand, $c'=(c_1,\dots,c_k,c_{k+1},\dots,c_n)^T=0$ (where $c_{k+1}=\dots=c_n=0$) by linear independence of $S$; this would be a contradiction.

Comment: what's the difference please?

Comment: What do you mean book's suggestions misleading? I think suggestions okay just the proof kind of unclear :(

Comment: @BCLC The difference is that your argument is invalid. About my judgment on the book's hint: suggesting a proof by contradiction and the "without loss of generality" is only complicating things, which are just applying the definitions instead.