# Finite superset of linearly dependent set is linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Larson Edwards Falvo - Elementary Linear Algebra

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

1. Does 58 follow from contrapositive of 57?
2. I'm not sure I follow the proof but based on previous question [Subsets of finite sets of linearly independent vectors are linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940958/) I think this is what it means:

WOLOG say $S_1 = \{u, u_1, ..., u_n\} \subseteq \{v, u, u_1, ..., u_n\} = S_2$

WOLOG say we have in $S_1$ that $$u = c_1u_1 + ... + c_nu_n$$

Then we have in $S_2$ that

$$u = c_1u_1 + ... + c_nu_n + 0v$$

Is that right?

Comment: I have the textbook you're referencing (it might be an earlier or later edition, though) - what page is this on?

Comment: A set is linearly dependent *if and only if* it is not linearly independent; the other exercise (n. 57) is completely equivalent to 58, after observing that 57 implies the more general statement “$S$ is linearly independent if and only if each of its subsets is linearly independent”.

Comment: @egreg Right but I wanted to understand the book's approach. It seems to not use contrapositives

Comment: @heather p. 220. This is in 4.4 Spanning Sets and Linear Independence

Comment: @BCLC If the smaller set is linearly dependent, one of its elements is a linear combination of (some of) the others; but this also holds in the larger set.

Comment: @egreg Yeah that's what I said right?

Comment: @heather Cmiiw, but I did that?

Comment: @BCLC, then what's your question? That's how the book seems to suggest it.

Comment: @heather I wasn't sure I understood proof. So I tried elaborating a little. My question is if I am right. Actually the book doesn't introduce any new vectors in $S_2$...

Answer (score 1):

There are several slightly different approaches possible.

One is the characterization of a linearly dependent set as one where one of the elements is a linear combination of (some of) the others.

So, if $S_1\subseteq S_2$ and $S_1$ is linearly dependent, then one of the elements $v\in S_1$ can be written as
$$
v=c_1u_1+\dots+c_nu_n
$$
with $u_i\in S_1$, $u_i\ne v$ ($i=1,2,\dots,n$). Then also $S_2$ clearly satisfies the same property, so it is linearly dependent.

(Note that the hypothesis that $S_1$ is nonempty is redundant, as the empty set is linearly independent.)

---

Another approach: you have proved the statement in exercise 57. This implies the more general statement that

> A set of vectors is linearly independent if and only if each of its subsets is linearly independent.

One direction is exercise 57, the other direction is trivial, because a set is a subset of itself.

Thus exercise 58 directly follows.